# Zoom Custom-made UserControl on Mouse-hover

Tags: c#, wpf

I've made a custom-made thumb which is inherited from the class Thumb.

```
public class MyThumb : Thumb
{
     //Properties
     //Constructors
     ...
     ...
}
```

I want it to be zoomed on mouse-hover by the user and then return back to its normal state when hovering is removed. I've wrote this in the App.xaml so that it can be applied on any thumb present in the Canvas area.

```
    <Style x:Key="MyThumb" TargetType="Thumb">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Grid.ZIndex" Value="1"/>
                    <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.1" ScaleY="1.1"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

But this isn't working.  The thumb is not zooming. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the style for the thumb will only apply to objects that have the `Style` property set like this:

```
<Thumb Style="{StaticResource MyThumb}" />
```

or

```
<local:MyThumb Style="{StaticResource MyThumb}" />
```

To use your custom thumb control you have to add the containing namespace (here named local) to an element (normally the root element of the document, but it can be any other as well) like this:

```
<Window ...
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1" />
```

"WpfApp1" has to be repalced by your namespace. Here the control is in the main namespace of the application. If the control would live in the sub-namespace "WpfApp1.Controls" you would have to write `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1.Controls"`. `local` can be repalced with any name you like (in newly created pages, user control, ...) local referes to the namespace the created element lives in, so you might need to add another namespace declaration to the file das described above. Additionaly the above does also apply to App.xaml where you add the style (or basically any other file you want to use the control in xaml).

The `x:Key` attribute does only define the key for the style within the resource dictionary that contains the style.

If you want the style to apply to both types by default you can create a style for `Thumb` objects and a style for `MyThumb` objects that is based on the former (if you just want the style to apply to all `MyThumb` objects you can omit the former and remove the `BasedOn` attribute on the latter style):

```
<Style TargetType="Thumb">
    <!-- Your setters and other stuff -->
    ...
</Style>

<Style TargetType="local:MyThumb" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Thumb}}">
    <!-- Additional setters and other stuff -->
    ...
</Style>
```

Note: In this case none of the styles has a key.

Comment: when i use the snippet provided by you , it gives an error 'MyThumb is not supported in the Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) Project' . Should i be doing something extra to fix this. Where should i set the style property. I'm new to WPF, kindly help

Comment: @RahulKurup I've updated my answer to adress your issues. The style has to be set like any other property (e.g. `Width` or `Height` on the element).